# Excel chart for displaying Yes or No values against list of features and companies

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have the following chart in excel. It has listed the features and companies who are supporting the features. Hence, It has Yes or No values in it.
I want to display nicely in excel chart. I tried using PivotTable report, but it didn't accept this data for pivottable. Could someone guide me what is the best excel chart for showing this report visually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use number like 1 or 2 in place of Yes and No and then using that you can create  bar graph depending upon which part (feature or company) you want to keep as base for this statistics.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier you can assign any value to Yes and No. In the below screen shot it is 1 for Yes and 0 for No. This is a simple bar graph in excel. Please explore other graph styles to suit your need.

This is just to give an direction to the thought process. 
Hope this helps.

[image: See the partial screenshot]

Comment: Good. I don't see bar chart in this vertical style. I get only in horizontal style in my MS excel, so instead of company in your case for me it is showing feature, which is not correct for me. But your chart shows better and correct. Do I need rotate my chart to visualize like your's or ? I am trying on Mac.

Comment: Please use stacked column style. You may have selected stacked bar style when creating the chart hence the horizontal bars.  You can select the chart area and then select 'Change Chart Type' from the top menu bar and select the one fitting your need. The above chart is done on Mac using excel 2015 for Mac. Hope this helps.

Comment: I selected stacked column only but it is reverse to me than your graph, i.e instead Feature 1, it is Company 1 for me, I'll try again and update. Thanks